# SimCity undestroyable small road

Tags: simcity-2013

I added a Bus Terminal to my city (the big kind). Later in the game, I noticed it basically disappeared leaving just a trail road and a small garage.

Annoyed, I decided to delete it and rebuild one. Except that deleting it only removed the small garage left. The small dirt road remained. I cannot delete it or build anything over it.

I tried to delete the main road next to it (hoping it will ask me if I want to delete the building too), but it didn't ask anything. Now I can't even rebuild the old roads because it says it cannot intersect the dirt road. I can't build over it for the same reason. 
Clicking to bulldoze doesn't do anything.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it could be one of the game's numerous bugs.

Comment: Have you tried placing buildings that use dirt roads around it?

Comment: it's a bug with buildings not removing its substructures, I think it's related to just bulldozing the road instead of the building first

Comment: I had the same problem with a consumer electronics factory. Never figured out how to fix it. I never deleted the factory, it just vanished, except for the garages and road around it. With adding zoning around it, small buildings did fill in around it though.

Comment: I've abandoned this city since...

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug that is not fixable short of the devs releasing a patch.  However you could attempt to fix this via natural disaster.  Unfortunately/fortunately natural disasters don't destroy roads.  However, if perhaps the game sees these roads in particular as part of a building (since they were used to upgrade one) then perhaps it will make an exception.  I recommend unleashing a earth quake or comet on it and seeing what happens.

Comment: I would +1 for the phrase "fix this via natural disaster" but I haven't played the game don't know if this is correct!

Comment: I'm interested in knowing if this works, so you should definitely let us know if you try it!

Comment: Can you "target" a natural disaster to a specific area?

Comment: I gave this +1 simply because its an educated good idea worth trying.

Comment: Natural disasters does not work. Road will still be there. Still figuring out how to destroy them roads. FYI, earthquake destroyed my large police station, school and large fire station. What a way to reach the target population of 600k with such a large space wasted unable to do anything to them